# Alternative to heater cartridge for 10mm deep hole?

Tags: heating-systems

In a design for a heated block I am working on I only have the space for a 6mm X 10mm hole for my heating element to be inserted into.

Originally I had planned to use a 40W heater cartridge but the smallest I can find is 6mm x 20mm and the extra 10mm that would stick out the block would be inconvenient as I want to insulate the area around this from the heat.

Is there a good alternative to a heater cartridge that would fit my specs?

Comment: Back in the day people used large resistors for heating elements...but i assume you only have a hole on one side...the heater carts are nice things..but i couldn’t find one only 10mm long either...can you change your block size?

Comment: I would be concerned about burning up a resistor that small in an enclosed space.  Resistor ratings typically assume air heat dissipation at normal ambient temp.  40W is a lot.

Comment: That's interesting, I hadn't thought of that. I could make it a through hole without much issue, I can't make the block much bigger due to access restrictions. Do you think a resistor would be suitable for temperatures around 200°C? @morbo

Comment: In this situation it would be enclosed by aluminium alloy 1xxx and operate at temperatures around 200°C, do you think these conditions could potentially lead to the resistor burning up? @ScottDunnington

Comment: I think it's a specialty application.  I wouldn't count on a regular ceramic resistor holding up.  This question might go better on the Electrical Engineering SE.

Comment: @FEA42 have a look at reprap extruders from before 2015~ all of then were just resistors that did normally 300c no problems...even my first 3d printer was with a resistor